# Using multiple model objects in a java spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm currently trying to make a website, where I have Item models, and User models.
I want to use the item controller to display information about a user and item, (which is stored in a mysql databse) on the same html page.

How would i go about this, without having to also inject the userService class into the itemService class?

Comment: can you show your code on how you are showing items on Html page right now? 
one suggestion would be to call userService from the itemController directly based on the item details.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to inject the userService into your itemService? There's nothing wrong with calling services from services

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from creating a service method that passes back a DTO containing both a User and an Item. You can inject multiple repositories into your service and retrieve both entities within the same transaction.

You could also provide separate methods in your service, one to get the user and the other to get the item, but in that case you would have two separate transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys, it helped me out a lot.
I was mainly just confused about the role of service classes I guess.
Now I'm using multiple repositories for my service class, which then sends a DTO back to the controller, with all the data it needs.